# Bootstrap Collapse not Collapsing

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a collapsable component using Bootstrap. My code is this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group Item #1
    </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The "Collapsible Group Item #1" when clicked should collapse the items in class "panel-body" but it doesn't there is no effect of click. I copied this code directly from Bootstrap documentation still it does not work. Can anyone figure out what is the problem?

Comment: Make sure you're not making a semantic mistake. I spent several minutes with this `data-bs-target="collapseExample"`. As you may notice at first, it seems to be good code, but there's a `#` missing. Instead, the correct code in BS5.1 is `data-bs-target="#collapseExample"`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

jQuery is required (if you're using Bootstrap 3 or 4) ;-)

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- THIS LINE -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any idea why this function would not work with https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js ?

Answer (score 118):

I was getting crazy for one hour... I reply to this question after 7 years, because if you are using the new **Boostrap 5**, the attributes are `data-bs-toggle`, `data-bs-parent`, and `data-bs-target`, pay attention to the **-bs-** in the middle.

Comment: You saved me hours of searching! Thank you 
Could you specify where you get the response, or is there an updated version of bootstrap docs that contains that info.. I am using bootstrap 5 a lot these days

Comment: Thank you, the top Google result of Collapsing defaults to the Bootstrap V4 docs :(, I'm guessing that is throwing a lot of people off.

Comment: Oh the frustration. Intellisense in VS2022 suggests the attributes without the `-bs-` part and I was getting nowhere. Which is.. well, `-bs-` ;)

Comment: The ```-bs-``` is such a bs

Answer (score 21):

bootstrap.js is using jquery library so you need to add jquery library before bootstrap js.

so please add it jquery library like

Note : Please maintain order of js file. html page use top to bottom approach for compilation

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 11):

Add jQuery and make sure only one link for jQuery cause more than one doesn't work...

Answer (score 7):

You need jQuery see bootstrap's [basic template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

Answer (score 7):

If using Bootstrap 4.5 collapse component, use these two links inside the body of HTML tag

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

You probably added two script files and you need to delete one of them

```html
<script src="./assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

delete bundle.min.js or bundle.js

Comment: for me, this one was the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

For me (with Bootstrap v5.1), the solution was to import the `transitions` SCSS partial (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/optimize/)

`@import "transitions";`

Comment: This solution is what worked for me.  Using Bootstrap 5.1.3 I needed `import transitions from "bootstrap"`.  I didn't have to use the imported `transitions` anywhere, but I believe it must have imported a needed dependency.  

[Here's a working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-accordion-icon-demo-j1nwf?file=/src/components/AccordionWithIcon.jsx)

Comment: The `transitions` SCSS partial contains the CSS styles for the collapse and expand animations. Without these transitions, the collapsing is not animated and therefore nothing happens in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and the problem was bootstrap.js wasn't load in Yii2 framework.First check is jquery loaded in inspect and then check bootstrap.js is loaded?If you used any tooltip Popper.js is needed before bootsrap.js.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest Bootstrap version.
Then you just need to replace this `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"` to this `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"`
and don't need to do more. It means you just need to remove `-bs-`

Comment: remove `-bs-` makes `version 5.1` not operate with the accordion effect.

Comment: This is wrong and is the opposite of what's needed to upgrade Bootstrap v4 to v5. v5 requires the -bs- added to the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Another good reason for this is either incorrectly formatted html, so things aren't closed up properly, or your id tags have things like full stops in them, that jquery will balk at.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue using bootstrap 5 and found I'm following bootstrap 4 instructions.
and followed BS 5 instructions and resolved.
here is the right working example
please check [Bootstrap5 collapse Example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/collapse/#content)

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-bs-target
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, it expands but it doesn't collapse what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to change the bootstrap cdn versions to check. try bootstap4 . Avoid bootstrap 5 as it is still in beta

Answer (score 0):

I use **bootstrap 5.2** and I had to import the collapse JS plugin to make it work:

`import collapse from "bootstrap/js/src/collapse";`

Importing `transitions` SCSS didn't have any effect.

It was also important, as others have already pointed out, that bootstrap 4 and 5 templates are slightly different.

bootstrap 4:
`data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"`

bootstrap 5:
`data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"`

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap nav to work "collapse" class you need to add bootstrap.js file in my case i added "bootstrap.bundle.min.js" for bootstrap version 5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I upgraded from Drupal 7 to Drupal 9. In Drupal 7, bootstrap 4 was used and `data-target` and `data-toggle` were working. In drupal 9, bootstrap 5 is used so needed to change to `data-bs-target` and `data-bs-toggle`.
Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when working on Vue JS 3 using Bootstrap Vue.

The issue was I had an extra bootstrap reference to a CDN on my index.html file that I did not need. I removed this from my index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-WW8/jxkELe2CAiE4LvQfwm1rajOS8PHasCCx+knHG0gBHt8EXxS6T6tJRTGuDQVnluuAvMxWF4j8SNFDKceLFg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

After removing that from index.html, all the code started working correctly. This is in BootStrap 5 and Vue JS 3. Make sure you don't have a redundant reference on Vue JS when using Bootstrap.

Answer (score -6):

Maybe your mobile view port is not set.
Add following meta tag inside `<head></head>` to allow menu to work on mobiles.

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```