# Collapse not working properly in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use collapse in a navbar using Bootstrap. When the collapse control shows and I click it, nothing happens.

I'm sure I put the jQuery and Bootstrap bundle scripts in the right place.

Manually collapsing it in the console using `$(".collapse").collapse();` works, though.

This is my entire page, if it helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>{{ title }}</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h6 class="display-6" style="font-family:monospace;color:orange;">jeweled</h6></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span style="color:white;">...</span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Stuff</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">{{{ body }}}</div>
<script src="static/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/wrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched for a little while and found how to fix this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66464814/14959808). Turns out, I needed to change the `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes to `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target`.

Answer (score -1):

Keep aware that depending on the version of the bootstrap a lot of things also change. For example, ms on bootstrap 5 is the same as ml on bootstrap 4.

Comment: Please see [answer] and take the [tour]. You need to provide more specific solutions.